# a collection of 20 marbles from infinite pool of 2 color marbles with replacement..

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have an infinite supply of pink  and blue marbles. Probability that any random draw will yield a  pink marble is "p" and prob. of picking blue is 1-p. Let us assume p=0.4 if a numeric value helps.

I have to first keep drawing till I collect a total of 20 marbles. I then have to see if this collection has >= 12 pink marbles. I make a note if this is true or not. I then randomly discard one of 20 marbles in my collection and draw one more fresh marble. I then do my inspection again to see if I have >= 12 pink marbles. I repeat this "inspect, note_result, discard, replenish" cycle a total of 100 times. What is the probability that after 100 cycles I will have encountered at least once a situation that I have >= 12 pink marbles in my side collection? (I can stop once I encounter this condition, or stop after a total of 100 inspections, which ever happens first. What is the probability that I will stop due to having found >= 12 pink marbles?)

I recognize that prob. of finding 12 or more pink marbles give p=0.4 is 0.056526367. I also know that if I discard all 20 marbles and start again, and repeat this 5 times for a total of 100 marbles drawn, prob. that in none of the 5 such tests I will find >=12 pink marbles is (1-0.056526367)**5. However, since I don't discard all the marbles and do replacement one at a time, I believe odds will be higher that I will encounter a condition of having >=12 pink marbles in my side collection. However, I am at a loss as how to compute this value.

Comment: This looks quite hard. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I have a system in which events occur every minute w/ a probability of "p". I have to accumulate first 20 samples before I can examine them for 12 or more successes. After that I have to keep discarding oldest event and take in a new event every minute. Each time I must examine if I have 12 (or more) out of 20 that I keep track of. I wanted to know the likelihood that I will encounter the condition in first 120 observations (20 initial and 100 more incremental after that.)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this question correctly and using the stopping condition given as

> (I can stop once I encounter this condition, or stop after a total of 100 inspections, which ever happens first. What is the probability that I will stop due to having found >= 12 pink marbles?)

then, wouldn't this piecewise recurrence yield the solution

- when $m < 11$
  $$p_{(k,m)} = p_{(k-1,m-1)} \frac{20 - (m-1)}{20}p_{s} + p_{(k-1,m+1)}\frac{m+1}{20}(1-p_{s}) + p_{(k-1,m)}\frac{m}{20}p_{s}
   + p_{(k-1,m)}\frac{20-m}{20}(1-p_{s})
  $$
- when $m = 11$
  $$p_{(k,m)} = p_{(k-1,m-1)} \frac{20 - (m-1)}{20}p_{s} + p_{(k-1,m)}\frac{m}{20}p_{s}
   + p_{(k-1,m)}\frac{20-m}{20}(1-p_{s})
  $$
- when $m = 12$

$$p_{(k,m)} = p_{(k-1,m-1)} \frac{20 - (m-1)}{20}p_{s}$$

where $p_{s}$ is the probability of choosing a pink marble (0.4 as the example in the question), $p_{k,m}$ is the probability that on the $k^{th}$ "cycle" there are $m$ pink marbles present, where $m \leq 12$. The initial conditions are for $k = 0$, where $p_{0,m}$ can be found readily.

Thus, the probability that we have exactly $m$ pink marbles in cycle $k$ requires us to come from having

- $m-1$ pink marbles in cycle $k-1$ (probability of this is $p_{(k-1,m-1)}$), then discarding a blue marble (probability $\frac{20 - (m-1)}{20}$), and then drawing a pink marble (probability $p_{s}$); or
- $m+1$ pink marbles in cycle $k-1$, then discarding a pink marble, and then drawing a blue marble (second term); or
- $m$ pink marbles in cycle $k-1$, then discarding a pink marble, and then drawing a pink marble (third term)
- $m$ pink marbles in cycle $k-1$, then discarding a blue marble, and then drawing a blue marble (fourth term)

In the cases where $m < 0$, $p_{k,m} = 0$ since it is not possible to have a negative count of pink marbles.

We are interested in computing $p_{k,12}$ for $1 \leq k \leq 100$.

Thus, and for example, $$p_{(1,12)} = \frac{9}{20}p_{(0,11)}p_{s}$$ since the only way to finish with 12 pink marbles on the first cycle is to have 11 pink marbles on the zeroth cycle, then to discard a blue marble (with probability $\frac{9}{20}$) and to replace it with a pink marble (with probability $p_{s}$).

It wasn't clear if the first cycle was forced regardless of the pink marble count on the zeroth cycle (initial draw of twenty marbles). I assumed it wasn't forced and the stopping condition would kick in.

Then I think the matter of seeing 12 or more pink marbles at least once should be readily answerable --- it ought to be $\sum_{k=1}^{100} p_{k,12}$. The "or more" is superfluous for $k >= 1$ since if we started with 12 or more, we would never proceed to the next cycle.

Comment: I think you're missing the case where you discard a blue marble and draw a blue marble.

Comment: silly yes. updating now.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how you deal with the stopping -- the general equation can't hold for all $k$ and $m$ as written, since it allows transitions from $12$ to less than $12$, but the text doesn't seem to specify any restrictions or modifications to prevent that.

Comment: the stopping condition I understood was "having greater than or equal to 12 marbles". I reasoned that if I had 12 marbles on cycle $k$, then there would be no cycle $k+1$ and hence i could never have more than 12 marbles except on the initial draw, no? maybe i misunderstood then?

Comment: No, that's all fine; it's just not clear to me how you reflect that in your calculation. Applying your recurrence as written would amount to continuing the draw after you've reached $12$ marbles. After re-reading your answer now, I get the impression that you're trying to solve this by talking about $p_{(k-1,m)}$ for $m\ge12$ as two different things depending on whether it occurs on the left-hand side or the right-hand side (you seem to say that it's zero only on the right-hand side) -- if so, that would be a very confusing abuse of notation.

Comment: oh I see what you're saying. maybe I should add that we never solve for $p_{k,m}$ for $m > 12$ to begin with since that state isn't possible (a la the stopping condition that I understand). I mentioned the right hand side because for $p_{k,12}$ we would have to deal with a $p_{k-1,13}$ term which I reason to be zero. or better would be if i gave a piece wise definition.

Comment: No, the values for $m\gt12$ are not the problem. You can define $p_{k,m}$ only up to $m=12$ and don't need to worry about the values for $m\gt12$. The problem is rather with the values for $m=12$. You want to use them to extract the result ($p_{100,12}$), so apparently they're not zero, but then they contribute to the values for $m=11$ in the next stage, which is wrong, since you would have stopped if you'd had $m=12$.

Comment: What you need, in Markov chain parlance, is an absorbing state at $m=12$, so that $m=11$ can transition to $m=12$ but $m=12$ doesn't transition to anything else; so there musn't be a contribution from $m=12$ to $m=11$ in the next stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41598/discussion-between-math-misery-and-joriki).

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughtful answer(s). I will try to learn from it and attempt to move forward. I note that my question has been flagged for being "off topic" or for not giving enough about my own efforts to answer the question. This is my first post to the forum so I apologize for not fully knowing all the rules/ettiquetes.